# Flexbox. Align items center not ignoring padding

Tags: html, css, flexbox

How to make `flex` child don't overlap top padding?

In this example child `.large` is centered middle, but its top is over top boundary of its parent because of its larger height. Is there a way to prevent this and make `.large` to be after `.flex` padding-top without JS? `flex-start` will be bad solution because blocks inside `.flex` can have small height and must be in the center of `.flex`. `.flex` must be positioned as `absolute` or `fixed`.

https://jsfiddle.net/zoxamy9f/1/

```css
.large {
  background: red;
  height: 200%;
  flex: 1;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.flex {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 10%;
  height: 100%;
  background: black;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="large"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe im not understanding good enough, but basically, if you have a width and height in %, you cannot use padding in %.
try giving width and height a fixed value in 'px'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add a wrapper between the `flex` and `large`, you can accomplish that

I also used viewport units `vh` instead of `%`, since percent won't work to enable vertical centering.

[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/zoxamy9f/3/)

Stack snippet - much content

```css
.wrapper {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100% - 10vh);
  justify-content: center;
}
.large {
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
}
.flex {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 10vh;
  height: 100%;
  background: black;
  overflow: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="large">
      Content 1
      <br> Content
      <br> Content
      <br> Content
      <br> Content
      <br> Content
      <br> Content
      <br> Content
      <br> Content
      <br> Content
      <br> Content
      <br> Content
      <br> Content
      <br> Content
      <br> Content
      <br> Content
      <br> Content
      <br> Content
      <br> Content
      <br> Content
      <br> Content
      <br> Content
      <br> Content
      <br> Content
      <br> Content
      <br> Content
      <br> Content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Stack snippet - little content

```css
.wrapper {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100% - 10vh);
  justify-content: center;
}
.large {
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
}
.flex {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 10vh;
  height: 100%;
  background: black;
  overflow: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="large">
      Content 1
      <br> Content
      <br> Content
      <br> Content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible by any chance that you could alter your structure to something like this?

```css
.large {
  background: red;
  height: 200%;
  flex: 1;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.wrap {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: black;
}

.flex {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-top: 10%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="flex">
    <div class="large"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```